# Flutter - TextField hint text padding is different than input text when focused vs unfocused

Tags: flutter, dart

If you look closely at the two pictures, you will notice that the default text hint ("Enter a search term") is closer to the bottom of the TextField than when the TextField is in focus after clicking on it.

I've tried tinkering with the contentPadding, and this is the closest I've been able to get them to match. But, it still is a little off, and I don't want to make the TextField unnecessarily tall to make the difference less obvious.

1. Why is the text not in the same vertical position when focused vs unfocused?
2. How do I get them to match?

[image: "Enter a search term" - default hint text]

[image: Position changed when on focus]

Here's my Widget code:

```
import 'package:Shrine/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'search_model.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Search extends StatelessWidget with ChangeNotifier {
  Search();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Consumer<SearchModel>(builder: (context, searchModel, child) {
        return IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            semanticLabel: 'search',
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            // Open dialog box with InputField.
            searchModel.toggleVisibility();
          },
        );
      }),
      Consumer<SearchModel>(builder: (context, searchModel, child) {
        return AnimatedOpacity(
            opacity: searchModel.isVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            child: Container(
                width: 190.0,
                height: 25.0,
                //color: Colors.green,
                child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: kShrinePink300,
                      hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 14.0, bottom: 8.0, top: 2.0),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      searchModel.updateText(text);
                      //onChange(text);
                      print('AnimatedOpacity changed');
                    })));
      })
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `CupertinoTextField`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### To fix this, use `OutlineInputBorder` for `enabledBorder`

You are having that problem because you set `enabledBorder` to `UnderlineInputBorder` and the text can't fit(having the underline, text and padding).

#### Also change the padding to something like this

`contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0),`

It's not good idea to limit the field height. The min tapable area should be around 40-44 points for mobile(people with big fingers will have hard time hitting it, especially if you have column with more than one TextField).